# Kafka consumer and producer for auto-generated case classes

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

I have the following use case - from a set of avro contracts - defined as .avsc files - I generate Scala case classes with the `avrohugger` library. 
I would like to submit different types of contracts to the same kafka topic.

When writing a publisher I need a way to specify that every unrelated contract can be passed to a `submission` method. As I have no control over how the classes are created from `avrohugger`, I define a type class which is a context bound to a generic input type (e.g. `T: Event`) and then submit the information to Kafka. That works.

My problem is how to define the consumer? I want to provide my clients with the ability to choose which message they want to work with e.g. `consumer(f: E => Unit): Unit`. And here is where I get stuck. `E` needs to be an abstraction - not a concrete implementation. This doesn't allow me to use a type class. But I cannot touch the case classes as I already mentioned. I can workaround the problem by having an `Out` counterpart for each contract but that is harder to maintain and it incurs an added cost of useless short lived object and object mappings.

Comment: "This doesn't allow me to use a type class" - Why?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov As far as I understand a type class will allow me to pass in concrete implementation in E and keep it concrete. And I don't want that. I want E to be an abstraction over all contracts such that the user can decide which contract they want. In other words a type class will be too concrete.